# get table like returned value while calling a procedure in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm a BigQuery SQL user and a newbie at Postgres.

When I call a procedure in Postgres that uses dynamic SQL for returning results, it doesn't give me results as like a `select * from xxx` returns.

It gives me a result in an array. That I can't use in my use case.

For example:
Consider this procedure

```sql
create or replace procedure sbx.count_rows_from_table_prc(pin_run_type varchar, pin_filter varchar, pin_table_name varchar, inout val_ record default null)
language plpgsql as
$$

    /*__________________SET VARIABLES_____________*/
    declare formatted_sql constant text := format(
        '
            select count(*) as num_rows
            from %s
            where %s
        ', pin_table_name, pin_filter
        );

    begin
        if lower(pin_run_type) = 'execute'
            then
                execute formatted_sql into val_;
        else
            select formatted_sql into val_;
        end if;

        /*__________________EXCEPTION_____________________*/
        exception when others then
            raise notice 'Error Message: %', SQLERRM;
    end
$$;
```

it returns

[image]

That means it returns all values in a `()` and I want it to return it like BigQuery.

on BigQuery, it returns

[image]

Is there any way, so that I can return a query result from the procedure or a function? Just like `select * from xxx` shows.

Comment: If you want to return values, use a function not a procedure. And that's not an array.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Function returns values. but doesn't returns a table like structure. It returns everything in `()` when the return type is set to `setof record`

Comment: This is all covered in the manuals. If you don't want to specify the types of your columns (i.e. RECORD) then you need to specify them when you call it.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I want these functions to be completely dynamic. if I specify the actual return types, I will lose the reusability of functions for any tables.

Comment: Be precise. You don't want them to be completely dynamic. That would just be "writing a new query". You want constrained changes and there are examples in the manuals